# Best practices for modeling deeply nested collections in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I am asking about what ID's I should and shouldn't be storing for deeply nested collections.

Let's say I have the following 4 collections, and am modeling as follows:

**Cities**

- id

**Libraries**

- id
- cityId

**Books**

- id
- cityId (??)
- libraryId

**Pages**

- id
- cityId (??)
- libraryId (??)
- bookId

The question that I have is should I be storing the values with the (??) next to it or should I just be looking those up through the collection that it belongs to.

For example, should I store the libraryId in each Page document or should I be looking up that value though the Book it belongs to.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on how they are queried. Can you envision a situation where you need all the pages in a city? If not then you probably don't need that denormalization.

Comment: Like David is saying, defining the 'access patterns' of your application will really help inform your schema decisions.

There's a good write-up here on the MongoDB blog about some rules of thumb http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3